# Read text and format in a word document using Openxml

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I've been trying to solve this my self but it seem that i really need help.

I am reading a Word document using OpenXml.

And i need the text in the word document and its format.

I have this code for getting the text and attributes

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);

            Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            foreach (var item in body)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(">>text: " + item.InnerText);
                foreach (var tt in item.GetAttributes())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tt.LocalName + " : " + tt.Value);
                }

            }
```

And the output of the code above is something similar to this

```
rsidR : 0067182C
rsidP : 002A2C9A
rsidRDefault : 004052D2
rsidR : 0067182C
rsidRDefault : 004052D2
rsidR : 0067182C
rsidSect : 0067182C
```

What i need is the format used in each text in the word document. But what are those means

And this is the screenshot of my sample Word document. Can i retrieve it like a property Bold. Font Name. Font size?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8P1k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can get the formatting information for each text.

I am assuming that you have all the runs. Each run has runProperties which has all the formatting information.

So iterate over each run and get the formatting like below.

```
bool Border = run.RunProperties.Border != null,
bool Bold = run.RunProperties.Bold != null,
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get with Descendants node and make loop on it then you can get what ever you are looking for.